# If a subgroup acts transitively on a set, then the index of the subgroup equals the index of the stabilizer?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove the following: If a subgroup $H < G$ acts transitively on a set $X$, then $[G:H] = [G_x:H_x]$ for any $x \in X$ ($H_x$ denotes the point stabilizer of $x$ in $H$.) Any hints would be appreciated.

(EDIT: I am mostly interested in the case where G and H are infinite. What if $X$ is infinite?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case where $G, H$ can be infinite:

Consider $H< H<G \Rightarrow [H:H_x][G:H] =[G:H_x]$ and $H_x<G_x<G \Rightarrow [G_x:H_x][G: G_x]= [G:H_x]$ .

$\Rightarrow [G_x:H_x][G: G_x] = [H:H_x][G:H]$. Since $[G: G_x]=[H: H_x] = |X|$, we're done.

Note: Can I assume $[G: G_x]=[H: H_x]$ even if $X$ is not finite?

Comment: Now one wonders whether one can get away without assuming $|X|$ is finite! I believe you mean to write $H_x$ as the first mathematical symbol of your second line.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I *would* like to get away with that.

Comment: Yes $[G:G_x]=[H:H_x]=|X|$ is always true, by orbit-stabilizer, but we're still stuck because we cannot divide by infinite cardinals (generally).

Comment: Is there any way that cancellation property can hold w/o X being finite?

Comment: The only way it'd be valid to cancel it is if $|X|<[G:H]$ (strictly).

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: Also-- that renders the utility of the theorem somewhat useless. :/

Comment: Because multiplication of two cardinal numbers always returns the larger of them. If $\kappa<\alpha$ then $\alpha\kappa=\beta\kappa$ implies $\alpha=\beta\kappa=\max\{\beta,\kappa\}$, in which the max cannot be $\kappa$ (we'd have a contradiction), so it is $\beta$, hence $\alpha=\beta$. This proves the cancellation property. For any instance of $\kappa\ge\alpha$ we can exhibit $\beta$ for which $\alpha\kappa=\beta\kappa$ but $\alpha\ne\beta$.